# ExpressibleBy#Literal with parameter pack "Cannot convert value of type '#ExpressibleType' to expected argument type '#Type'"

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uikit, parameter-pack

I'm trying to create a generic function to apply some image filters.

The `applyFilters(_:)` function uses **Parameter Pack** of `ImageFilter`.

Calling `applyFilters(_:)` with static functions that take a type literal I got the error:

> Cannot convert value of type `#ExpressibleType` to expected argument type `#Type`.

But creating an object directly from **`ImageBlurFilter.Radius`** or **`ImageExposureAdjust.Scalar`** work fine.

```swift
protocol ImageFilter {
    
    associatedtype Processor: ImageFilterProcessor
    /**/
}

protocol ImageFilterProcessor { /**/ }

struct ImageBlurFilter: ImageFilter {
        
    init(radius: Radius) { /**/ }
    
    struct Processor: ImageFilterProcessor { /**/ }
    
    struct Radius: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
        
        init(integerLiteral value: Int) { /**/ }
    }
}

struct ImageExposureAdjust: ImageFilter {
    
    init(scalar: Scalar) { /**/ }
    
    struct Processor: ImageFilterProcessor { /**/ }
    
    struct Scalar: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
        
        init(floatLiteral value: Double) { /**/ }
    }
}

extension ImageFilter where Self == ImageBlurFilter {
    
    static func blur(radius: ImageBlurFilter.Radius) -> ImageBlurFilter {
        ImageBlurFilter(radius: radius)
    }
}

extension ImageFilter where Self == ImageExposureAdjust {
    
    static func exposureAdjust(scalar: ImageExposureAdjust.Scalar) -> ImageExposureAdjust {
        ImageExposureAdjust(scalar: scalar)
    }
}

func applyFilters<each Filter: ImageFilter>(_ filter: repeat each Filter) {
    let _ = (repeat (each filter))
}

func test() {
    applyFilters(
        .blur(radius: 10), // ❌ Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'ImageBlurFilter.Radius'
        .exposureAdjust(scalar: 0.5) // ❌ Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'ImageExposureAdjust.Scalar'
    )
    
    applyFilters(
        .blur(radius: ImageBlurFilter.Radius(10)), // ✅
        .exposureAdjust(scalar: ImageExposureAdjust.Scalar(0.5)) // ✅
    )
    
    let blurRadius: ImageBlurFilter.Radius = 10 
    let exposureAdjustScalar: ImageExposureAdjust.Scalar = 0.5
    
    applyFilters(
        .blur(radius: blurRadius), // ✅
        .exposureAdjust(scalar: exposureAdjustScalar) // ✅
    )
}
```

Comment: I think this is a compiler bug.

Comment: Take a look at SnapKit framework. You can also customize it further if needed.